# Mail Chimp - Add form to email template

Tags: php, forms, email, iframe, mailchimp

I am trying to add a form to my Mail Chimp Emailer using the code tool and then adding my form code, but when I preview the Emailers, the form and checkboxes are striped out:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/Emailer.php">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ancaster" /><label for="ancaster">Ancaster</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="beamsville" /><label for="beamsville">Beamsville</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="binbrook" /><label for="binbrook">Binbrook</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collingwood" /><label for="collingwood">Collingwood</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hamilton" /><label for="hamilton">Hamilton</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="kitchener" /><label for="kitchener">Kitchener</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="stoney-creek" /><label for="stoney-creek">Stoney Creek</label><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Here" style="background-color:red; border:0; color:#FFF;" />
</form>
```

I have also tried uploading my form to a server and use an iframe, but that didn't work either, when I goto preview it, its strips the iframe. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to send an HTML form in the body of an email?

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Comment: Given that mailchimp's brand is based on an easy to use email system, targeting non-technical content creators I would be willing to bet their system is set up to filter out the 'questionably supported' HTML elements from the emails. This prevents their non-technical user base from trying to implement something they don't understand and distributing bad (unusable) content to their mailing lists. **So to answer your question, it has limited support in some email clients as @ceejayoz pointed out with the links, but it is not good practice to use it because of this limited and varied support.**

Comment: https://twitter.com/mailchimp/status/139443588584058880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms will not work in an email. Neither will iframes.  You should figure out a design that will prompt the user to click through to your form.

HTML emails are VERY limited in terms of what HTML can be supported. Basically think of it as the web in 1998.

Comment: Forms and iframes *will* work in *some* email clients.

Comment: @user979331Mailchimp probably works to protect you against doing stuff that'll break in most email clients.